# What is the best way to store Text Messages? Something like SMS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I´m writing a small prgramm in which the User is able to send small Messages (460 Characters). Now I want something like a History in which the user can see all Messages he ever send from this App inlucing the recipient and the Text, both are Strings.
Is Core Data "to much" for this? Any other Idea?

Thank you

twickl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use either Core Data (is not too much for this) or straight SQLite API.